# Find the relation in which the plane divides the edge of the tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

The tetrahedron ABCD is given . The points M, N and K lie on the edges AD , AB and BC, respectively, and AM:MD = 2:3 , BN:AN = 1:2 and BK:KC = 1:1. Construct a section of the tetrahedron with the MNK plane. In what respect does this plane divide the edge CD?

*P.S. It is forbidden to use Menelaus' theorem for a tetrahedron.*

I connected the points N and K, M and N, K and P (the point on the edge of CD). Built a straight MP parallel to a straight NK. Thus, I built the MNK plane (MNKP). How to find the DP:PC I don't know.

Comment: Your idea of constructing the parallel to $NK$ is fine, but $MP$ is not parallel to $NK$. If the parallel cuts plane $BCD$ at $Q$, then $P$ is the intersection of $KQ$ with $CD$.

Comment: I'd suggest you to set up coordinates such that $B=(0,0,0)$, $C=(1,0,0)$, $D=(0,1,0)$ and $A=(0,0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the line through $M$ parallel to $NK$ intersect plane $BCD$ at $Q$ (see figure).
The intersection $P$ between lines $QK$ and $CD$ is also the intersection
of plane $KMN$ with $CD$.

Drop perpendicular lines $AH$, $ML$, $NI$ to plane $BCD$.
We have $ML={3\over5}AH$ and $NI={1\over3}AH$,
hence
$$
ML={9\over5}NI
\quad\text{and}\quad
MQ={9\over5}NK.
$$
Construct $F$ on line $BD$ such that $MF\parallel AB$.
We have
$$
MF={3\over5}AB={9\over5}NB.
$$
Hence triangles $MQF$ and $NKB$ are similar, $FQ\parallel BC$ and
$$
FQ={9\over5}BK={9\over10}BC.
$$
If $FQ$ intersects $CD$ at $E$, then $FE={3\over5}BC$ and
$$
QE=FQ-FE={3\over10}BC={3\over5}KC.
$$
Finally, $PC={5\over3}PE={5\over8}EC$ and $EC={2\over5}DC$, that is:
$$
PC={1\over4}DC.
$$

[image]